# Why can I not have the date and time in one cell

Tags: mac, numbers

I want to start at a date and at 12:00:00 am and I want each cell to increase by 1 hour. I put `=a2+time(1,0,0)` but I keep getting "The formula’s arguments can only include one date value." What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need a formula to display a date and a time together in Numbers but a formula would make life easier if you also wanted to have a list of cells with incrementally increased times on an hourly basis.

First, select (click on) the cell where your initial date is. Then, select the "Format" icon on the Numbers toolbar at the top and then select the "Cell" tab. In the Cell tab, choose "Date & Time" as the Data Format and then choose one of the Date format options in addition to one of the Time format options in the separate drop-down menus for Date and Time. The cell you just formatted should appear similar to

> 5/10/18 12:00 AM

after these actions.

In order to display in another cell the time and date in the cell A2 as increased by one hour, you can use the following formula which utilizes the hour specification allowed in formulas. If the cell A2 has the starting date and time, put down the formula

> = a2 + "1h"

, for example, into the cell right below (the cell A3) to get a date and time one hour later than the one in the cell a2. Assuming the cell A2 has the date and the time I used as an example previously, the cell A3 would appear similar to

> 5/10/18 1:00 AM

after entering the formula and pressing return.

You can have the further incrementally increased hours as a list of dates & times if you copy and paste the formula in A3 to the cells below it.

Comment: In addition to "h" for hours, you can use "w" for weeks, "d" for days, "m" for minutes, "s" for seconds, and "ms" for milliseconds. You can specify multiple units of time as well. For example, if you want the new date to be 3 days later than the one in the cell a2, you can use the formula = a2 + "3d".

Answer (score 1):

Welcome to Ask Different. To get both date and time in a column, click on the column you wany this in, as in A or B or... After that make sure the Format button in top right of the sheet is selected. Then go to the sidebar on the right and select CELL. Near the top of the sidebar is a pull-down under the label Data Format.  Select Date and Time from the pulldown menu. Once you've selected this a date and time appear in a single cell. See figure below from numbers. I entered the date as 2/5/20 1pm and i got the number displayed in the image.

[image]

To change the value in the next cell add 1. This changes the day by 1, + 365 changes the year by 1. Fractions change the time. The value 0.000012 will change the time by 1 sec. And 60 times that, or 0.000694, changes the time by 1 minute.